# import error in parallel folders python django cant be fixed with PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, django, windows, import

[django structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pafqz.png)

this is my django structure I am trying to import "home_view" function from Pages APP to main urls in "Kianwoodco" project

these statements seem to be not working

```
from ..Pages.views import home_view 
from src.Pages.views import home view
```

also importing views is giving out the same error as result

errors :

no module name 'src'

attempted relative import beyond top-level package

any help would be appreciated I have tried

```
sys.path.append("#path to Pages")
```

and adding **init**.py to src

Comment: your manage.py and db.sqlite3 in on "pages" folder ?

Comment: No its in the src folder I could go by include method to fix the problem and run my project as I want but yet couldnt find a way to import "pages.views" inside "kianwoodco.urls"